# Dash app re-performs early caching steps after loading server

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When I spin up my Dash app, I do a bunch of once-off tasks - pulling in the data I'll need, etc.  However, it seems like Dash is performing them twice: once at the point I'm asking for them to happen in the script, and a second time once it's loaded the server up.

Here's a simple example of what I'm talking about:

*module_link_test_source.py*

```
print("Source module")

def source_module_function():
    print("Source function")

    return 1
```

*module_link_test_destination.py*

```
import module_link_test_source as source
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

print("Destination module")
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

function_run = source.source_module_function()

app.layout = html.Div()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I run `python module_link_test_destination.py`, here's what the console spits out:

```
Source module
Destination module
Source function
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app "module_link_test_destination" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Source module
Destination module
Source function
```

I would only expect those `print()` statements to have executed once each.  How do I make these steps only occur once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are seeing this behavior because you are running in debug mode. Try setting `debug=False` in the `run_server` call.

Comment: Since I still wanted the debug stuff, I went with `use_reloader=False` instead, but the same idea applied.  Thanks!